# Local clone with modified files with Git

Tags: git

I am looking for a way to copy the modified / uncommitted changes in the clone destination (staged or not).

```
git clone --shared src dest
```

It would be nice to have a --modified, or would that be a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, and it would be a really odd thing to do. Git’s datamodel works on the base of commits, and whenever you transfer data between a local and a remote repository, you are essentially copying commits and labels around.

This inherently means that in order to transfer anything to a different repository, you need to commit those changes. And that is a good thing because a commit is a fixed and unchangeable thing in a repository. Uncommitted changes are not, so it’s incredibly difficult to reference them properly. It would be a huge mess. In addition, you would be breaking the intention behind committing completely, since you could suddenly transfer changes without committing, without making the deliberate choice to “seal off” a package of changes with author information and an explanation.

Finally, when cloning in particular, you are cloning a remote repository. In most situations, such a remote repository is a *bare* repository and as such has no working directory. As such, it would also have no way of having uncommitted changes anyway.

So no, it would not be a good idea, and it would also likely not work properly anyway.

Comment: Well, the goal is to write a script that makes the equivalent of autotools "distcheck", that is copy all known files in a tarball, and check the build works (without having to commit, I mean do you commit before running your tests? no). So the script would create a copy/link in a temporary directory, it's not meant to be a working directory.

Comment: though I should be able to do that quite effectively with `git ls-files --recurse-submodules` instead

Comment: *“I mean do you commit before running your tests? no”* – I can run local tests without committing. Tests on a test server run with CI after I commit and push though. That’s what feature branches are for.